# How to Stop Service of Music Background?

Tags: android

I need a background music which is continuously playing through Activities. I want to stop my background music when clicking on the Home Button.

**This is my Service Code.**

```
public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service
{ 

private static final String TAG = null;

MediaPlayer player;

Context context;
private int length = 0;

public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
              return null;   
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.haha);
    player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
    player.setVolume(100,100);



}
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    player.start();
    return 1;

}
 @Override
  public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

   player.start();

  }

  public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {

  return null;
}

public void onStop() {
    player.stop();
    player.release();
    player = null;
}
public void onPause() {

    player.pause();

        }

public void onHomePressed(){
    player.stop();

}
public void pauseMusic()
{
    if(player.isPlaying())
    {
        player.pause();
        length=player.getCurrentPosition();

    }
}

public void resumeMusic()
{
    if(player.isPlaying()==false)
    {
        player.seekTo(length);
        player.start();
    }
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(player != null)
    {
    try{
     player.stop();
     player.release();
        }finally {
            player = null;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {


}

public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "music player failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(player != null)
    {
        try{
            player.stop();
            player.release();
        }finally {
            player = null;
        }
    }
    return false;
 }
 }
```

**This is my 1st Activity Class**

```
 public class AdventureTime extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.story);


    Intent svc=new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
    startService(svc);  

    View story1 = this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    story1.setOnClickListener(this);

    View story2 = this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    story2.setOnClickListener(this);

    View story3 = this.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    story3.setOnClickListener(this);

    View back= this.findViewById(R.id.buttonback);
    back.setOnClickListener(this);

}
            @Override
            public void onBackPressed(){

              new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle("Exit")
              .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
               .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                          Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                                          intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                                          intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                          startActivity(intent);
                                          System.exit(0);

                                       }
             }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
            }  

public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.button1:
        Intent button1 = new Intent(this, Story1.class);
        startActivity(button1);
        break;

    case R.id.button2:
        Intent button2 = new Intent(this, Story2.class);
        startActivity(button2);
        break;

    case R.id.button3:
        Intent button3 = new Intent(this, Story3.class);
        startActivity(button3);
        break;

    case R.id.buttonback:
        Intent buttonback = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(buttonback);
        break;


    }     
 }
}
```

Comment: Override onPause() method in which use your "pauseMusic()" method.

Comment: public void onPause() {
     
     player.pause();
     if(player.isPlaying())
  {
   player.pause();
   length=player.getCurrentPosition();

  }
         }

Like this?

Comment: like this, but do not forget to stop your service.

Comment: Where to stop? 
    @Override
    public void onStop(){
       Intent svc=new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
        stopService(svc);
        super.onPause();

    } This in the activity class?

Comment: The music still won't stop when I pressed Home button

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the Activity `AdventureTime` :

```
...
@Override
public void onPause(){
    stopService(svc);
    super.onPause();

}
...
```

Comment: The music still playing when I press the Home button.

Comment: @KarinaDabu Are you sure this method has been called when you press home button? Add a log to onPause function to verify that. Tell me if it works.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just new in Android. What is a log to?

Comment: write some System.out.println("test"); statement so that you will know that this method got executed or not. and check it in logcat

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pause music without stopping your service
try this
add this class in your service

```
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    BackgroundSoundService getService() {
        return BackgroundSoundService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
```

and add this in your activity

```
private BackgroundSoundService mBoundService;

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        mBoundService = ((BackgroundSoundService.LocalBinder)service).getService();

    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {

        mBoundService = null;

    }
};
```

replace

```
    startService(svc)
```

with

```
    bindService(svc, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

and call the pause method in service whenever u need it

```
mBoundService.pauseMusic();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to listen to a dispatchKeyEvent instead? You could write:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
        stopService(svc)
        return true;
    }
    else
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
  }
```

on each of your activities.

Answer (score 0):

on you mainActivity class add this.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
// pause or stop ung Background music here.
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```