# play music with background service

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, background-service

I'm trying to play music with a background service. Firstly, I have a `toggle button` in `MainActivity` for playing and pausing music. I also created 
`BackgroundSoundService` just for playing music in all activities and not to play in the background:

```
public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = "BackgroundSoundService";
MediaPlayer player;

public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onBind()" );
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.vaporv2);
    player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
    player.setVolume(100,100);
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate() , service started...");

}
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    player.start();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onUnBind()");
    return null;
}
public void onStop() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onStop()");
}
public void onPause() {
    if(player!=null && player.isPlaying()){
        player.pause();
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "onPause()");
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    player.stop();
    player.release();
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate() , service stopped...");
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onLowMemory()");
}
  }
```

and `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     MusicButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);

    MusicButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (MusicButton.isChecked()) {
                //mediaPlayer.pause();
                Intent myService = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
                startService(myService);
            } else {
                //mediaPlayer.start();
                Intent myService = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
                stopService(myService);
            }
        }
    });
```

My problem happens when I pause the music and play it again. The music starts from the beginning when I want it to continue from where it left off. My second problem is that I don't want to play music in the background, I want stop music when the app is in background.

Comment: Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27685889/how-to-stop-service-of-music-background) for stopping music while it's in background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what your `onPause()` and `onStop()` are meant to do. However when you start a service for the first time using `Context.startService()` the `onCreate()` method of the service is called and then `onStartCommand()` is called and later when you call `startService()` again only the `onStartCommand()` is called. So for whatever reason if you want to play the sound in a service and pause that in the very same service, you need to provide the service an `Action` that specifies the action you want to do.

So in your activity when you want to tell the service to play the sound:

```
String action = "PLAY";
Intent myService = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
myService.setAction(action);
startService(myService);
```

and to pause the sound:

```
String action = "PAUSE";
Intent myService = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
myService.setAction(action);
startService(myService);
```

and in the `onStartCommand()` method in your service:

```
if (intent.getAction().equals("PLAY")) {
    // resume the sound
}
if (intent.getAction().equals("PAUSE")) {
    // pause the sound
}
```

and when you really need to stop the service meaning `Destroy` the service, call `context.stopService()` and only then `onDestroy()` method is called and the service is really destroyed.

Comment: thanks so much it's work but music still playing  in the background i put this code `Intent myService = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
        getApplicationContext().startService(myService);` in my `onDestroy()` in mainactivity

Comment: please music still playing in the background

Comment: @S.Queroane I'm not sure what is your problem exactly. Do you want the music to be stopped when your service is destroyed?

Comment: i want to stop music when user go in background ( for example when user click in home button ) and when return in my app music continue from where it left off

Comment: @S.Queroane Then override `onResume()` and `onPause()` methods of your activity. When activity is resumed, resume the sound just like you did before and when activity is paused, pause the sound the same way.

Comment: i don't how i can do that please help me

 `@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }`

Comment: @S.Queroane What you are asking is going far from the title and the content of your main question. Please read about [Activity Lifecycle on developer page](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html).

Answer (score 0):

To prevent playing in background override on Activity pause then pause you service there and to resume where you left of save the current position in a preference then retrieve it when needed